# passing a set of attribute to a component incase it is selected else passing another set of props if not selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
                 {this.state && this.state.conditionAgreed ? (
                        <Icons icon="roundCheckCircle1" fill="#436ab2" />
                      ) : (
                        <Icons height="26px" width="26px" icon="circle" />
                      )}
```

I want to pass  the set of  props of (fill, icon) or (height,width,icon) depending on the situation but in one go to my Icon component .What's the way to achieve that in react?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (example with functional component):

```
YourComponent = () => {
  ...
  const props = conditionAgreed ? 
     {icon: "roundCheckCircle1", fill:"#436ab2"} :
     { height:"26px", width:"26px", icon:"circle"}
  return (
     <Icon {...props} />
  )

}
```